# np.around for array with none and integer values

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array:

```
MDP= [[0.705,.655,0.614,0.388],[0.762,None,0.660,-1],[0.812,.868,0.918,+1]]
```

How can I apply np.around on above array without getting the error for None and -1, +1 values?

TIA

Comment: With `None`, that isn't a numeric array.  As written it is a list (of lists).  `np.array(MDP)` will be an object dtype array.  Also, are the `-1` and `+1` integers or strings?  Integer `1` isn't displayed as '+1`.

Comment: `np.around` applied to a object dtype array results in an error, even for the float elements.  It complains that the element doesn't have a `rint` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you work with a numpy array, not lists of lists:

```
np.around(np.array(MDP).astype(float))
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
#       [ 1., nan,  1., -1.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

You can convert the result back to a nested list with `.tolist()`, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to make an exception when the values inside the array are of `NoneType`. This can be done pretty elegantly via a `lambda` function.

If your array is 1D:

```py
flex_round = lambda array: [None if x == None else np.round(x) for x in array]
```

If your array is 2D:

```py
flex_round = lambda array: [[None if x == None else np.round(x) for x in y] for y in array]
```

Do not forget to add the `decimals` argument to the `np.roud` call to precise how many digits should remain after the comma.